# Prevent transliterate from replacing unknown characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transliteration

[transliterate](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/transliterate) replaces unknown characters with question marks "?" by default. Instead, I would like for it to leave them as is.

This is the default:

```
I18n.transliterate("日本語")
# => "???"
```

This is what I want:

```
I18n.transliterate("日本語")
# => "日本語"
```

How can I accomplish this?

If this is impossible (I think transliterate coverts everything to UTF-8/US-ASCII), I would at least like to raise an exception when a replacement occurs. I've been trying to set `raise` to true but that hasn't worked.

Comment: You can provide a custom implementation of transliterate as Proc for i18n configuration, as described [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/transliterate).

Comment: @raina77ow thank you. I'm very new to ruby, could you help me with this implementation?

Comment: it looks like I would just need to write a function to handle this (I assume a proc has some limitations just like lamdas). What I don't get is how I can write "for any unknown characters, do nothing" in code